# Как получить DOM страницы по url

Tags: javascript, dom, chrome-extension

из расширения Crome пытаюсь получить DOM-структуру страницы по ссылке. Использую такой код:

```
            var doc = document.body;
            fetch(order_data['skuhref']).then(function(response) { 
                response.text().then(function(text) {
                    doc.textContent = text;
                });
            });
```

В этой переменной order_data['skuhref'] находится url.

Скрипт возвращает страницу в виде html текста. А как получить страницу в виде DOM, чтобы удобно можно было обращаться к нужным элементам?

Comment: вот тут ты вполне мог использовать парсер из прошлого вопроса. так как в text лежит разметка Html - ты получишь нормальную структуру

Comment: Я пробовал не получается, результат, насколько помню null

Comment: Если тебе приходит html - результат не может быть null

Comment: Вот что получается <body>[object HTMLBodyElement]</body>

Comment: Это ты как проверяешь?

Comment: var parser = new DOMParser();
var sku_document = parser.parseFromString(doc, "text/html");
console.log ("skudoc_document", sku_document);

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112296/discussion-between-grundy-and-sturmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно создать `div` элемент и в `innerHTML` положить полученный html.

```js
var doc = document.body;
fetch(order_data['skuhref']).then(function(response) { 
    response.text().then(function(text) {
        doc.textContent = text;

        let dom = document.createElement('div');
        dom.innerHTML = text;

        // теперь можно пользоваться селекторами как обычно
        console.log(dom.querySelector('h1'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Не понял, как это работает, но работает!

Comment: Мы просто создаём в памяти новый элемент(`div` в данном случае), а содержимым делаем html нужной нам страницы. Т.е. как если бы мы на странице имели такой код: `<div><html><body>some text<body></html></div>`.

Могу предложить ещё почитать документацию: [Element | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element), [document.createElement | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement)

Comment: спасибо! протестил 2 варианта Ваш и Grundy. Расширение уже введено в эксплуатацию.

Answer (score 1):

По совету  Grundy сделал вот так:

```
fetch(order_data['skuhref']).then(function(response) { 
            response.text().then(function(text) {               
                var parser = new DOMParser(); 
                var sku_document = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");   
                ........                    
            });
        });
```

Просто, красиво и работает!

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет про браузер, то в браузере уже есть DOM:

```
const dom = window.document;
```